# In Spark, caching a DataFrame influences execution time of previous stages?

Tags: apache-spark, caching

I am running a Spark (2.0.1) job with multiple stages. I noticed that when I insert a `cache()` in one of later stages it changes the execution time of earlier stages. Why? I've never encountered such a case in literature when reading about caching().

Here is my DAG with `cache()`:

[image: myDAGwithCache]

And here is my DAG without `cache()`. All remaining code is the same.

[image: myDAGwithoutCache]

I have a `cache()` after a sort merge join in Stage10. If the `cache()` is used in Stage10 then Stage8 is nearly twice longer (20 min vs 11 min) then if there were no `cache()` in Stage10. Why?

My Stage8 contains two broadcast joins with small DataFrames and a shuffle on a large DataFrame in preparation for the merge join. Stages8 and 9 are independent and operate on two different DataFrames.

Let me know if you need more details to answer this question.

**UPDATE 8/2/1018**
Here are the details of my Spark script:

I am running my job on a cluster via spark-submit. Here is my spark session.

```
   val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("myJob")
      .config("spark.executor.cores", 5)
      .config("spark.driver.memory", "300g")
      .config("spark.executor.memory", "15g")
      .getOrCreate()
```

This creates a job with 21 executors with 5 cpu each.

Load 4 `DataFrames` from parquet files:

```
val dfT = spark.read.format("parquet").load(filePath1) // 3 Tb in 3185 partitions
val dfO = spark.read.format("parquet").load(filePath2) // ~ 700 Mb
val dfF = spark.read.format("parquet").load(filePath3) // ~ 800 Mb
val dfP = spark.read.format("parquet").load(filePath4) // 38 Gb
```

Preprocessing on each of the `DataFrames` is composed of column selection and `dropDuplicates` and possible `filter` like this:

```
val dfT1 = dfT.filter(...)
val dfO1 = dfO.select(columnsToSelect2).dropDuplicates(Array("someColumn2"))
val dfF1 = dfF.select(columnsToSelect3).dropDuplicates(Array("someColumn3"))
val dfP1 = dfP.select(columnsToSelect4).dropDuplicates(Array("someColumn4"))
```

Then I left-broadcast-join together first three `DataFrames`:

```
val dfTO = dfT1.join(broadcast(dfO1), Seq("someColumn5"), "left_outer")
val dfTOF = dfTO.join(broadcast(dfF1), Seq("someColumn6"), "left_outer")
```

Since the `dfP1` is large I need to do a merge join, I can't afford it to do it now. I need to limit the size of `dfTOF` first. To do that I add a new timestamp column which is a `withColumn` with a UDF which transforms a string into a timestamp

```
val dfTOF1 = dfTOF.withColumn("TransactionTimestamp", myStringToTimestampUDF)
```

Next I filter on a new timestamp column:

```
val dfTrain = dfTOF1.filter(dfTOF1("TransactionTimestamp").between("2016-01-01 00:00:00+000", "2016-05-30 00:00:00+000"))
```

Now I am joining the last `DataFrame`:

```
val dfTrain2 = dfTrain.join(dfP1, Seq("someColumn7"), "left_outer")
```

And lastly the column selection with a cache() that is puzzling me.

```
val dfTrain3 = dfTrain.select("columnsToSelect5").cache()
dfTrain3.agg(sum(col("someColumn7"))).show()
```

It looks like the `cache()` is useless here but there will be some further processing and modelling of the `DataFrame` and the `cache()` will be necessary.

Should I give more details? Would you like to see execution plan for `dfTrain3`?

Comment: We definitely need more details here. In general this is not unusual, but details depend on the particular scenario. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/6910411 for hints, how to create useful examples.

Comment: @user6910411 Added more details about the job as requested. Thanks.